# paste text to foreground window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I want my program to paste a text to a carret position of an foreground window (notepad, word, openoffice or even a web browser).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;

private void listBox_Data_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, "It works!");
    IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_PASTE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

So, I got this so far and it is not working.

Comment: Have you already tried posting a WM_PASTE message to hWnd?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it didn't work for me. It is also very possible I did a mistake or smth. I will try one more time.

Comment: Okay this is how I did it. Is it coded properly?

Comment: Yes, and no. WM_Paste causes whatever is on the clipboard to be pasted into the control that receives the WM_Paste message, so you can't pass the content along with the message, you need to copy it to the clipboard instead.

Comment: And this is my main problem. OpenOffice seems to have its own clipboard or smth. And when I copy text from notepad and try to paste it through my App to OpenOffice Writer, it pastes the text I copied earlier from OO Writer. So I want to perform a paste of an indicated text. Any ideas?

Comment: `GetForegroundWindow()` is not enough. That tells you the top-level active window, but not the particular child window that has keyboard input. For that, you need to then use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` and then either `AttachThreadInput()` and `GetFocus()`, or `GetGUIThreadInfo()`. Then send `WM_PASTE` to that input window.